# Retrieve Source Settings from custom TFS Activity

Tags: tfs

In a custom TFS activity, I am trying to get access to the following value defined in my build  definition.

[image]

Where is this stored?  I can't see it in an Environment Variable.  I also looked all over the IBuildDetail retrieved with a Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities.GetBuildDetail activity, but I am not able to find the value anywhere.

I need this before the sources are retrieved.

Can someone help?  Much thanks!

Comment: Which part of the work flow? After the sources have been retrieved? In that case you can use the VersionControlClient to query the workspace configuration for your src folder.

Comment: Good point.  Actually before the sources have been retrieved.  Updated the question to reflect that.

Comment: I'd personally reflector the activity that creates the work flow. It must know :). My phone doesn't let me.

Comment: I am perusing TfGetSources using Reflector, but I am not able to make heads or tails of it.  Might be obfuscated b/c the variable names aren't helpful at all.

Answer (score 0):

The `CreateWorkspace` Activity uses the following line to grab the WorkspaceMappings:

```
 Mappings = new InArgument<List<IWorkspaceMapping>>(env => buildDetail.Get(env).BuildDefinition.Workspace.Mappings)
```

If you have Reflector or dotPeek or IlSpy, look at:

```
private Activity CreateBody();

Declaring Type: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities.CreateWorkspace 
Assembly: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow, Version=12.0.0.0
```